# Get cross-spectral density of specific frequencies in R

Tags: r, signal-processing

I am using cpsd (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsignal/gsignal.pdf) to find the cross-spectral density between two signals. It seems that there is no way to define the frequencies I want to get the density for. E.g. in MATLAB I can do `cpsd(x,y,window,noverlap,f,fs)`, where `f=[2,10]`, so the output will be only two values. Is there an alternative for R?